# conflicting return values of generic find function in class (C++), what to return?

Tags: c++, hashtable

I have a method in my class which called "find()" that returns a pointer to the data stored in the class (the class is hash table to be precise). I find this a bad idea to return a pointer to my class' data, and i haven't found anything better. any suggestions about how to find the data without being afraid that the user may delete (modify) my object ? 
this is the find method:
(the class is hash-table, it works completely find)

```
Data* find(const Key& key) {
    if (isMember(key) == false) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int hash_idx = hash_function(key, table_size);
    return &(*((table[hash_idx])->find(key)));
}
```

Comment: Use iterators and return `end()` if not found?

Comment: What about using references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a pointer to const then:

```
Data const* find(Key const& key);
```

Comment: If you want to be sure that a user will not be able to delete your data then you should return a copy (for example using optional). Otherwise you'll never be sure. One can try to delete data under the pointer or perform a const cast agains it

Comment: You don't need a `const` cast to `delete` something pointed by a `const` pointer. `delete` [can be called on `const` pointers.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22731af5ab783e98)

Comment: @user2146414 - library interfaces should be designed to protect against reasonable mistakes, not stupidity. It is highly unimportant that "you'll never be sure"; if the user screws up **their** data by doing something obviously stupid it's not your problem. Don't impose copying as a way to avoid that kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the usual problem with containers. Basically it boils down to the following:

You need two versions of `find`:

```
Data const * find(Key const &) const;
Data *       find(Key const &); // non-const
```

Clearly you can use iterators instead of pointers, but this solves nothing on its own. Then you'd need a `const`-iterator `const`-version and a (non-`const`)-iterator (non-`const`) version.

In order to get ideas on these kinds of design decision, I recommend consulting the STL ie. [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [`unordered_map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) in this case.